# Bootstrapping Aurelia

Tags: aurelia, jspm

Finally, I start to work with Aurelia. There is a starter kit available [Here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/getting-started) which facilitates initializing Aurelia. But it is a template which should be used within a *Web Site* template.

I have a pre-configured `WebApi` project and I want to use Aurelia in it. I've just added the starter kit files and folders to my project. But unfortunately it shows `27651` errors fo files in `jspm_packages`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any Nuget bootstrapper for Aurelia available?

Comment: hey, thanks for giving aurelia a try. unfortunately, I wouldn't know where to start with what you're experiencing. however, i'll relay your idea for a nuget bootstrapper to aurelia's vs team! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Start with the aspnetcore template from [Here](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation)

You can use web api from the template.

You will be up and running in minutes.

Comment: Is there something similar that doesn't have all the stuff in the project I don't need like karma?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I resolve this by just deleting testing folders.

Comment: That helps but removing the unneeded dependencies would be a plus too.

Comment: The Aurelia skeleton projects and clients add a lot of libraries.  If you are just learning I suggest starting with a blank directory and add the libraries you need.  This will help you understand what each library is for and also pare it down to the ones you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Web API, starting from an MVC5 project might be faster.

The following link is an Aurelia starter kit with MVC5.

You will have to update it to the latest version of Aurelia, but I managed to make it work with web api 2 and oAuth authentication.

https://github.com/rmourato/Mvc5-Aurelia

A tutorial can be found here.

http://ruimourato.com/2016/01/26/running-aurelia-on-mvc5.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well you asked what the errors are from. First thing is that you should exclude the jspm_packages folder from VisualStudios solution explorer Right click on it and mark 'exclude from project'.

Next, setup your project on source control (git) if not already and add the following to your git .ignore file

```
jspm_packages/
node_modules/`
```

I would suggest creating a second project aside from your WebAPI project that can contain static html, css and js files and do your Aurelia application there separate from your Web API project but in the same solution.

I could possibly give you a solution that is already setup, that shows how to use web api along with aurelia. But it would take some time for me to setup.

Answer (score 0):

For all of my projects using Aurelia, I use the aurelia-cli which you get through npm and I would also recommend this approach.

You can be up and running with hello world in under 5 minutes.
You will then be able to build all the appropriate bits and pieces to talk to your api.

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/1